# How to access items from the beginning and from end in one for statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
thislist = ["start1", "start2", "start3", "start4", "end4", "end3", "end2", "end1"]

for item in thislist:
    print(str(item) + str("is for ") + str(reversed(item))
```

The above example which i tried doesn't make any sense.
The result which I wanted is :

```
start1 is for end1
start2 is for end2
start3 is for end3
start4 is for end4
end4 is for start4
end3 is for start3
end2 is for start3
end1 is for start1
```

What i am trying to achieve is to use same list in a reversed way in the same for statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `zip()`.

```
thislist = ["start1", "start2", "start3", "start4", "end4", "end3", "end2", "end1"]

for item, rev_item in zip(thislist, reversed(thislist)):
    print(item, "is for", rev_item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate through list and reverse of the list simultaneously:

```
thislist = ["start1", "start2", "start3", "start4", "end4", "end3", "end2", "end1"]

for x, y in zip(thislist, thislist[::-1]):
    print(f'{x} is for {y}')

# start1 is for end1
# start2 is for end2
# start3 is for end3
# start4 is for end4
# end4 is for start4
# end3 is for start3
# end2 is for start3
# end1 is for start1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution that does not involve `zip()`.

```
thislist = ["start1", "start2", "start3", "start4", "end4", "end3", "end2", "end1"]

for i in range(len(thislist)):
    print(thislist[i] + " is for " + thislist[len(thislist) - i - 1])
```